# Text is missing when I try to scrape from a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the main text from a news article from the London Stock Exchange, but when I try to pull it using BeautifulSoup it does not appear. Does anyone know how I can pull this information?

I can find the tags when I click inspect, however when I view the source code (Ctrl + U), the text does not appear. I think that the information might be being loaded onto this site from another, however I am not sure of this and do not know how to scrape it.

The website I am looking at is: https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/PFG/interim-results-for-six-months-ended-30-june-2020/14665452

I am trying to pull the main contents about the Interim Results.

Comment: Please, Add a relevant piece of the code you are using and the wrong output/values you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is stored within the page inside `<script>` tag. You can use this example to extract it:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/PFG/interim-results-for-six-months-ended-30-june-2020/14665452'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select_one('#ng-lseg-state').string.replace('&q;', '"').replace('&l;', '<').replace('&g;', '>').replace('&a;', '&').replace('&s;', "'")
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

def find_news_article(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == 'newsArticle':
                yield v
            else:
                yield from find_news_article(v)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            yield from find_news_article(v)

article = BeautifulSoup(next(find_news_article(data))['value'], 'html.parser')

# print text from article on screen:
print(article.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
RNS Number : 1348X
Provident Financial PLC
26 August 2020
Provident Financial plc
Interim results for the six months ended 30 June 2020
Provident Financial plc ('the Group') is the leading provider of credit products to consumers who are underserved by mainstream lenders. The Group serves c.2.2 million customers and its operations consist of Vanquis Bank, Moneybarn, and the Consumer Credit Division ('CCD') comprising Provident home credit and Satsuma.

...and so on.
```